# Make Android client detect Java Server program using NsdManager

Tags: java, android

I have an application where a server socket runs on the computer, and client on Android phone. To connect the two, I had to manually type the IP of the server on the client end.

To make the detection better, I used NsdManager on the Android side to detect devices on the local network. My question is, what can I do /use in my Java Server side program, to have it broadcast something in the network that will be picked up by NsdManager.discoverServices() ?

Can someone please help?

Thanks